# Postfix, Edited sasl_passwd and now email is not relaying

Tags: linux, postfix-mta

So I'm running Postfix 3.1.0 on a work server. It's relaying emails to AWS SES and I just updated the access key. I removed the previous value in `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and then ran `postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and email was failing authentication.  Then I `systemctl restart postfix` and still no auth success. The only information I can find is regarding the postmap command and that should JUST WORK.

Like I said I logged onto a working system.. created a new access key in IAM. Put that new into into `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and thats the only change I've made.  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up being a missing [ in the sasl_passwd file. In case anyone encounters the same issue, the process is pretty damn bulletproof outside of user error.

Comment: 2FA uses an app password.  That special password is what you put in the sasl_passwd file?